# Pressing back button after navigating to an inner component closes Salesforce1 app in Android

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, android, navigation

I am facing an issue where the app gets closed when back button is pressed after navigating to an inner component in all Android devices.

When back button is pressed after navigating to an inner component, the app gets closed, instead of navigating back to the previous component as is the case in iOS devices and in Desktop.

I've created an unmanaged package for easily replicating the issue.

Here's the link to install the package:- https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tB00000009ZWH

> After installing, please go to Setup-->Salesforce1 Navigation and add
>   Highcharts Demo to the menu items.

Steps to replicate:-

1. Open Salesforce1 app in Android.
2. Navigate to the inner component by clicking any of the point in the chart displayed.
3. Press back button.

Result: The app gets closed

Expected: Navigate back to the previous component

PS:
Salesforce1, Version 13.0, Build number 30
| Android version 7.0